# Highcharts: create a stacked columnrange chart

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts

Basically, I would like to create a chart like this:

[image: An overlapped columnrange chart]

This seems nearly achievable with the `columnrange` chart type. The closest that I have come is with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BnnCt/8/). Any ideas how I might be able to get closer? One of the main issues with the fiddle is that colors are assigned to individual series rather than to all ranges in a specific category (i.e., the intended behavior is that all ranges plotted in a single category have the same color). Thanks much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately in Highcharts you can set only individual color for each series or point. Not for a specific range/category. See: http://jsfiddle.net/BnnCt/9/

```
        name: 'Temperatures3',
        data: [{
            low: 17,
            high: 22,
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 250, 0.3)'
        }, {
            low: 21,
            high: 26,
            color: 'rgba(0, 200, 250, 0.3)'
        }]
```